# How to show second action sheet on clicking a button in first action sheet, Swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am able to show the `editPhotoActionSheet` by calling `showActionSheetToEditPhoto()`.

When I click delete button in `editPhotoActionSheet` I would like to show `deletePhotoActionSheet`, but I am not able to do so with the below code. 
Please advice how I could achieve this.

Also see both action sheets below.

```
func showActionSheetToEditPhoto()  -> UIAlertController {

    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
    let takePhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed Take Photo")
        self.takePhoto()
    }
    let choosePhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed Choose Photo")
        self.choosePhoto()
    }
    let editPhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed Edit Photo")
        self.editExisitingProfilePhoto()
    }

     let deletePhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
     print("User pressed Delete Photo")
     self.showDeletePhotoActionSheet()

     }

    let cancel : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed Cancel")
    }

    alertController.addAction(takePhoto)
    alertController.addAction(choosePhoto)
    alertController.addAction(editPhoto)
    alertController.addAction(deletePhoto)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

    return alertController
}

func showDeletePhotoActionSheet()  -> UIAlertController {
    print("showOptionsToDeletePhoto function called")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // Dismissing previous alert

    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
    let deletePhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed delete Photo")
        var existingPhoto = self.profilePhoto.image
        if existingPhoto != nil{
            self.profilePhoto.image = nil
        }
    }

    let cancel : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed Cancel")
    }

    alertController.addAction(deletePhoto)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

    return alertController
}
```

**EditPhotoActionSheet**

[image: EditPhotoActionSheet]

**DeletePhotoActionSheet**

[image: DeletePhotoActionSheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `showDeletePhotoActionSheet` return `UIAlertController` instance but you have not used that object to present the action sheet. So present the action alert in your deletePhoto action.

```
let deletePhoto : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .default) { (alert) in
     print("User pressed Delete Photo")
     let alert = self.showDeletePhotoActionSheet()
     //present delete the action sheet
     self.present(alert, animated: true) //Or self.present(self.showDeletePhotoActionSheet(), animated: true)
}
```